# Open Closed approach to mapping correct entity properties to relevant view models

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns, webforms

I have inherited an existing application that has a list of SQL Database Views used for reports that are full of pre-processed result data that are broken up by a report type and value type and they are then used to show only weekly data.

An example of these views would be:

```
PlannedByFooView
PlannedByBarView

ProgressByFooView
ProgressByBarView
```

Entity Framework is then used to get relevant Entities from these database views and the entities are being used in all sorts of places in the application, one part being converted to a data table and used as a data source for a pivot grid :(

They have some similar properties like the below, that are expected in all reports

```
long ItemNumber { get; set; }
int Period { get; set; }
int Quantity { get; set; }
int Max { get; set; }
int Min { get; set; }
int Average { get; set; }
string Category { get; set; }
```

and then some specific properties too, such as `PlannedCode, ProgressDescription` that may appear in a few of the views or just one of them.

Here is an example of the report types, value types and a new period type that I now need to support.

```
public enum ReportTypes
{
    Planned,
    Progress,
    Complete,
    Released
}

public enum ReportValueTypes
{
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz,
    Qux
}

public enum ReportPeriodTypes
{
    Week,
    Month
}
```

I have changed the Database views slightly to the below structure as one example:

```
PlannedByMonthView
PlannedByWeekView
```

and then within each view they have the relevant fields i.e. `QuantityAsFoo, QuantityAsBar.. MinAsFoo, MinAsBar` etc.

**My problem is that now I need a way to materialise some view models from EF based on the report type that is required.**

**I can't see a nice OCP approach that doesn't involve lots of classes at the moment so I am looking for some help, preferably one that doesn't involve a large amount of nested switch statements.**

Example idea of getting a large number of data rows as a particular view model, using LINQ to Entities:

For Planned by month and by Foo (PlannedCode is specific to this view only)

```
myDbContext
    .PlannedByMonthView
    .Select(
        x => new PlannedViewModel { 
            PlannedCode = x.PlannedCode, 
            Period = x.Period, 
            Quantity = x.QuantityAsFoo, 
            ... 
    });
```

For Progress by week and by Bar (ProgressDescription is specific to this view only)

```
myDbContext
    .ProgressByWeekView
    .Select(
        x => new ProgressViewModel { 
            ProgressDescription = x.ProgressDescription, 
            Period = x.Period, 
            Quantity = x.QuantityAsBar, 
            ... 
    });
```